# Unable to compare the integer with the operator in powershell?

Tags: powershell

Unbale to compare the interger value in powershell using the -gt or -ge operator

Iam trying to get the latest number of files as a count in to a int variable. After i got the count, i need to check if it is greater than n number. But it doesn't look the value is comparing.

```bsh
[int]$count_of_Files= Write-Host (Get-ChildItem $source_dir | Measure-Object).Count

 if($count_of_Files -gt 3){Write-Host "True
"}
```

The count_of_files value is 6. But when i ran the if condition to compare the value > 3 , the output "True" not printing

Appreciate if anyone can help on this?

Comment: Remove the `Write-Host`, it isn't doing what you think it is.

Answer (score 0):

When creating a variable, do not use the `Write-Host` command ever, it will not assign it to the variable thus making it a NULL variable. Also try not to use strings for a Boolean when you can use `$True` or `$False`

```
[int]$count_of_Files = (Get-ChildItem $source_dir | Measure-Object).Count

 IF($count_of_Files -gt 3){
    $True
} Else {
    $False
}
```

Comment Answer: Normally you should ask a new question if it is not related to your initial question, but since it is a simple adjustment of the original code, please see below.

```
# Get files only from $source_dir
$Files = Get-ChildItem $source_dir -File

# Created if statement to check if there are more than 3 files in the $source_dir
 IF($Files.Count -gt 3){
    # Assigns the top 3 files to $files_to_keep with most recent at the top
    $files_to_keep = $Files | Sort-Object LastWriteTime -Descending | Select-Object -first 3
}
```

Comment: Hi @Drew. Thank you for the answer. that make sense. By the way, what iam trying to do inside the 'if loop' is to do some other operation as such getting the latest files if the condition is true. Below is my code

```powershell

IF($count_of_Files -gt 3){

$files_to_keep=Get-ChildItem -Path $source_dir | Where-Object { -not $_.PsIsContainer } | Sort-Object LastWriteTime -Descending | Select-Object -first 3
}

```
when i tried to do 'with out' the 'if loop' , code there in inside would work. Iam not sure where it got stuck. 
Appreciate if can help on this

Comment: @HariUmesh I have updated the answer to incorporate your comment request.